# Postgres connection gets ETIMEDOUT in deployed Firebase function (works locally)

Tags: postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, node-postgres

I wrote a couple Firebase functions that make use of node-postgresql to make requests to an external PostgreSQL database hosted on Amazon (RDS), using this generic behavior:

```
import { Client } from "pg"
import { config } from "firebase-functions"

export async function sendQuery(query, args?) {
  // use firebase environment config
  const client = new Client(config().postgres) 
  await client.connect()

  const res = await client.query(query, args)

  await client.end()
  return res
}
```

**This code works fine locally**, it can access either my local Postgres server or the Amazon RDS one without a problem.

When I deploy my cloud functions which make use of this `sendQuery` function, and try to trigger them, here is what I am getting from the logs:

> { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432
>       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
>   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
>   syscall: 'connect',
>   address: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
>   port: 5432 }"

The server address and port are correct, so I'm assuming the credentials were correctly sent through the firebase config. Outbound GET requests using bluebird work fine, even on random ports. I am starting to wonder if calling an external database is even possible... Any ideas?

Also, just in case anyone is wondering, **I am *not* on a free spark plan** so this must not be the issue:

[image: Blaze plan]